# printing out (input and output process) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, user-input

I think I'm almost there with my assignment.  I'm trying to print: 
"Hi John,(new line)
You have a 89.6% in your principle of programming course."  However, when I print the below, it shows as follows: 
"Hi John,(new line)                                                                                                                                                                        You have a 89.4 % in your principle of programming course."
So could you guys help me how to put % sign without space?  Are there better way to print these words?

```
student_name = input("Enter student's name: ")
course_name = input("Enter course name: ")

quizzes_weight = input("Enter quizzes weight: ")
projects_weight = input("Enter projects weight: ")
activities_weight = input("Enter activities weight: ")
attendance_weight = input("Enter attendance weight: ")
exams_weight = input("Enter exams weight: ")

quizzes_average = input("Enter quizzes average: ")
projects_average = input("Enter projects average: ")
activities_average = input("Enter activities average: ")
attendance_average = input("Enter attendance average: ")
exams_average = input("Enter exams average: ")

quizzes_weight = float(quizzes_weight)
projects_weight = float(projects_weight)
activities_weight = float(activities_weight)
attendance_weight = float(attendance_weight)
exams_weight = float(exams_weight)

quizzes_average = float(quizzes_average)
projects_average = float(projects_average)
activities_average = float(projects_average)
attendance_average = float(attendance_average)
exams_average = float(exams_average)

average_score_for_course = ((quizzes_weight * quizzes_average) + 
(projects_weight * projects_average) + (activities_weight * 
activities_average) + (attendance_weight * attendance_average) + 
(exams_weight * exams_average)) * 100

print("Hi",student_name +",","\nYou have a", 
average_score_for_course,"% in your", course_name,"course.")
```

for this assignment my above programming should produce output as below according to my input coding.
For example:

```
Enter student's name: Ryan
Enter course name: Advanced Quantum Mechanics

Enter quizzes weight: .1
Enter projects weight: .2
Enter activities weight: .3
Enter attendance weight: .1
Enter exams weight: .3

Enter quizzes average: 1
Enter projects average: .85
Enter activities average: .9
Enter attendance average: .95
Enter exams average: .87
```

the output should be something like this:

```
Hi Ryan,
You have a 89.6% in your Advanced Quantum Mechanics course.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format a string with the 3 variables you want to print:

```
print("Hi {},\nYou have a {}% in your {} course".format(student_name, average_score_for_course, course_name))
```

Comment: Wheres you explanation?

Comment: For example, you could link to the doc and quote it

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
print("Hi",student_name +",","\nYou have a", 
average_score_for_course,"% in your", course_name,"course.")
```

When you use a comma delimiter for the print function, it adds a space by default. Replace your comma with a +:

```
print(average_score_for_course + "% in your")
```

By replacing the comma with +, it removes the space that Python adds by default.

Using Emma's solution (string formatting) is a better and more pythonic solution to your problem. Hopefully I helped you to understand why this is happening, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just for a different answer:
You can try this as well

```
average_score_for_course = str(((quizzes_weight * quizzes_average) + 
(projects_weight * projects_average) + (activities_weight * 
activities_average) + (attendance_weight * attendance_average) + 
(exams_weight * exams_average)) * 100)+"%"

print("Hi",student_name +",","\nYou have a", 
average_score_for_course,"in your", course_name,"course.")
```

change the result to string and concatenate "%" to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Hi" + str(student_name) +"," + "\nYou have a" + str(average_score_for_course) +"% in your" + str(course_name) + "course.")
```

For me i will try to avoid using comma because it hard to visualize how your printing looks like and for safe it is better to convert "average_score_for_course" into str before printing.

Comment: Wheres you explanation?